# global variables names in optimized ELF binary

Tags: global-variables, elf

**Why ELF files keep the actual names of global variables?** rather than just keeping their addresses. Here is an example file:

```
int oren; int moish;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc>3)
    {
        oren=2;
        moish=5;
        return oren+moish;
    }
    return 8;
}
```

I compiled it and looked for moish with

```
$ gcc -O3 main.c -o main
$ objdump -D ./main | grep "moish"
```

I was a bit surprised to find the actual name moish inside (since I'm not sure
what it is needed for):

```
 504:   c7 05 06 0b 20 00 05    movl   $0x5,0x200b06(%rip)        # 201014 <moish>
0000000000201014 <moish>:
```

Any reason to keep it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was a bit surprised to find the actual name moish inside

UNIX binaries traditionally keep the symbol table in linked binary (executable or DSO) to assist in debugging. The symbol table is not used for anything else, and you can remove it from the binary using `strip` command, or linking with `-Wl,-s` flag.

After `strip` the disassembly looks like this:

```
105a:       c7 05 c8 2f 00 00 05    movl   $0x5,0x2fc8(%rip)        # 402c <__cxa_finalize@plt+0x2ffc>
```